# How to Look at a Gem's Code

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation

I have a Gem that I found at RubyForge and want to peek inside to see what code it contains. Is it possible to do this without installing the Gem on my system?

Also, if I use RVM on Mac OS X, does that at all change how my gems get installed (assuming I have one gemset)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gems on RubyGems usually have a link to the source code (most often on [GitHub](https://github.com/)), in which case you can easily browse the code (I use this A LOT).

The "homepage" link also tends to link to the repository.

If all else fails, go to GitHub and search for the name of the gem (you may need to match up the authors to ensure it's the right repository for the gem).

**Edit**:

Just noticed that you asked about gems on Rubyforge. In which case my first step would be to check [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org). But otherwise you will need to download the gem and peek inside it (it's just a compressed archive so you can open it up in something like 7-zip).

Comment: Hmm... looks like this particular Gem doesn't have a link to the source. In fact, the version of the gem on RubyGems is outdated -- the current one is on RubyForge (also no link to source).

Comment: Ah. Can you point us to this Gem? Maybe someone knows where to find the actual source. In any case you can download the gem and peek inside it (like any other compressed archive).

Comment: OK, doesn't look the source is available for this. In which case, download the gem, but don't install it, then open it in 7-zip (or simmilar).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [Dnsruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/dnsruby/) which has it's [source](http://rubyforge.org/scm/?group_id=2387) available.

Answer (score 8):

`gem unpack` unpacks the gem without installing it.

Answer (score 1):

Many gems have their source freely readable. The way that always works is to install it.

If you just want to browse the source; go to the gem on http://rubygems.org find your gem and use the "Source code" link.

In case of RubyForge you can find the links under the SCM link in the menu.